# Can "aroma" be associated with perfume?

Tags: word-choice

Can **aroma** be associated with perfume? I think that it is usually associated with food. I’m writing a technical document and would like to be precise.

What is the difference if I choose the words **scent/odour/smell/fragrance**?

Sentence:

> The seed powder is the most influential ingredient in giving the fragrance.
>
> Therefore, odour is added in the formula to reduce it (the fragrance).

Comment: Do you want answers for British English specifically, or for English in general?

Comment: Do you want answers based on the technical jargon of the perfume industry, or based on the sales jargon of the perfume industry, or based on how ordinary people normally use the words to describe how a woman wearing perfume smells?

Comment: It's not a commercial purpose, but more technical (research). I've been thinking people will associate it with food if I use **aroma**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster, the word [**aroma**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aroma) is not defined as being *only* associated with food, although it has that as a common theme.

> **1 a** : a distinctive, pervasive, and usually pleasant or savory smell • the *aroma* of freshly-baked bread ; *broadly* : ODOR
>   **b** : the odor of a wine imparted by the grapes from which it is made • The wine has a fruity *aroma*.
>   **2** : a distinctive quality or atmosphere : FLAVOR • the sweet *aroma* of success

Note in particular the last sense where **aroma** is used metaphorically to describe success.

It goes on to mention the shades of meaning between the various synonyms:

> SMELL, SCENT, ODOR, AROMA mean the quality that makes a thing perceptible to the olfactory sense. SMELL implies solely the sensation without suggestion of quality or character. • (an odd *smell* permeated the room) • SCENT applies to the characteristic smell given off by a substance, an animal, or a plant. • (the *scent* of lilacs) • ODOR may imply a stronger or more readily distinguished scent or it may be equivalent to smell. • (a cheese with a strong *odor*) • AROMA suggests a somewhat penetrating usually pleasant odor. • (the *aroma* of freshly ground coffee)

For its definition of **perfume**, it uses **scent** and **odor**, along with the generic **smell**:

> **1** : the scent of something sweet-smelling
>   **2** : a substance that emits a pleasant odor; *especially* : a fluid preparation of natural essences (as from plants or animals) or synthetics and a fixative used for scenting

An analysis of **perfume**-related synonyms is also given:

> FRAGRANCE, PERFUME, SCENT, REDOLANCE mean a sweet or pleasant odor. FRAGRANCE suggests the odors of flowers or other growing things. • (the *fragrance* of pine) • PERFUME may suggest a stronger or heavier odor. • (the *perfume* of lilacs) • SCENT is very close to perfume but of wider application because more neutral in connotation. • (*scent*-free soaps) • REDOLANCE implies a mixture of fragrant or pungent odors. • (the *redolence* of a forest after a rain)

Given all of that, I would say that **aroma** would not normally be associated with **perfume** more readily than one of the other synonyms. However, it could be used in such a way if, for instance, the scent were vanilla and it was being associated with the smell of that food ingredient:

> This vanilla perfume has a pleasant aroma.

In other words, unless using a neutral word (such as **scent** or **smell**) pick the individual word that best matches the specific association.

Note, too, that while the other synonyms apply to the *quality* of the smell, **odor** applies to the *quantity* (or *strength*) of the smell. That's why perfumes have a strong **odor** to start (so that they are noticeable to others), and then are further defined by the nature of their scent.